# WINDCLASSEX: необъявленный идентификатор Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

**Добрый день!**

Обучаюсь по книге **Станислав Горнаков - "DirectX 9: Уроки программирования на С++"**.
В первом уроке возникли осложнения - я ранее на С++ писал только консольные приложения.
Компилятор ругается в процедуре **WinMain**:

```
int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hinstance,
                    HINSTANCE hprevinstanсe,
                    LPSTR lpcmdline,
                    int ncmdshow )          
{
    WINDCLASSEX windowsclass;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    windowsclass.cbSize = sizeof(WINDCLASSEX);
    windowsclass.style =  CS_VREDRAW|CS_HREDRAW|CS_OWNDC|CS_DBCLKS;
....
```

Ошибка: WINDCLASSEX: необъявленный идентификатор.

Делал все покниге. Обычное оконное приложение. 
Все ли я необходимое выложил чтобы можно было мне помочь? Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что за тип такой **"WINDCLASSEX"** ? Такого типа нет в `WinApi`, понимаете? Вы просто опечатались, видимо, перепутав этот ошибочный тип с типом (структурой) описания оконного класса:

```
  WNDCLASSEX
```

Вот и все проблемы =)

Comment: Я гуглил WINDCLASSEX, а мне гугл выдавал WNDCLASSEX, уже мне тогда надо было догадаться, что это опечатка. Прискорбно, но эта ошибка находится в книге (эл. вариант). Спасибо за ответ!